# Want to build a digital picture frame

Tags: display

I've searched on the message board and can't find an answer to my questions, or at least one that definitively answers it. Also, in case it's important, I am a Pi Newbie. Just got one, and still climbing the learning curve.

So, I want to build a digital picture frame for my girlfriend. I have a Pi 3, and an old LCD monitor. A ViewSonic VX2035wm, to be specific. I looked up the specs, and it says it has a TFT active matrix display.

I have read some threads where people talk about where you can run into troubles trying to connect LCD screens, but nothing so specific as "you can't use TFT and connect to Pi without an adapter". I don't want to tear apart this monitor to find I can't connect, but I also don't want to order a screen and still wonder if I could've used it instead.

So, can anyone help me with my conundrum?

Answer (score 1):

The specification for that monitor says it has a DVI input. You just need an HDMI to DVI cable. The Pi should detect the monitor fine.